# auto submit form with if statement is true

Tags: php, facebook

I have been looking for a tutorial or something similar, but i cant seem to find how to auto submit a form with an if and else statement.

Im using facebook SDK and want to save the fb credential to the db if the user is logged in with facebook.

```
      <?php if ($user): ?>
  <input type="submit" name="facebook" id="facebook"/> // # TODO: auto submit. 

            <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
            <?php endif ?>
```

The submit button in using AJAX for saving to the database, but i would like to change the button to be auto submitting if the if statement is true.

Comment: PHP is a server-side technology.

Comment: @Virus721 You know, run the  <input type="submit" name="facebook" id="facebook"/> if the statement is true, without user interaction

Comment: Without interaction, i.e on page load ? If you know what to do before showing the page to the user, just load the right page. There's no point showing a form if the user can't type stuff in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit happens client-side, so you'd need to emit some client-side code that submits the form.  It *might* be something as simple as this:

```
<?php if ($user): ?>
    <input type="submit" name="facebook" id="facebook"/>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("facebook").click();
    </script>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

This would immediately invoke the `click` event on the `submit` button as the page is rendering.

Be careful with this sort of thing, though.  It's not always a good user experience to try to invoke client-initiated actions on behalf of the user.

Comment: Of course! i didn't think of using an javascript to do this. how could i be so dumb.:(